# Free linux kernel driver memory

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a generic question on freeing the memory of linux kernel driver.

I am writing a basic PCI driver where I want to free some memory of the device instance in the remove function of the driver. The memory is allocated in the probe function.

I have a question that when remove function of the device is called, does it guarantee that the read/write functions of the driver are not in progress or not entered, so that we can free the allocated memory and not lead into a panic due to access of invalid (or freed) memory area?